# ubuntu - mysql start and restart issue on ubuntu 16.04 server

Tags: mysql, ubuntu-16.04

i installed mysql 5.7 but then found out I need mysql 5.6 so i deleted all mysql related packages with

```
apt-get remove --purge mysql*
```

so it gotten removed. then i issued:

```
apt-get install mysql-server-5.6 mysql-client-5.6
```

so the mentioned packages gotten installed.
but its not starting using `systemctl start mysql` or `service mysql start` or even restart. the result is this:

```
service mysql restart
or
service mysql start
or
systemctl restart mysql
or
systemctl start mysql
```

returns:

```
Job for mysql.service failed because the control process exited with error code. See "systemctl status mysql.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
```

but

```
systemctl status mysql
```

returns

```
 mysql.service - LSB: Start and stop the mysql database server daemon
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/init.d/mysql; bad; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Mon 2017-04-10 13:24:00 EDT; 29s ago
     Docs: man:systemd-sysv-generator(8)
  Process: 15820 ExecStart=/etc/init.d/mysql start (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
 Main PID: 1323 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)

Apr 10 13:23:30 server mysqld[15926]: 2017-04-10 13:23:30 15925 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.8
Apr 10 13:23:30 server mysqld[15926]: 2017-04-10 13:23:30 15925 [Note] InnoDB: Using Linux native AIO
Apr 10 13:23:30 server mysqld[15926]: 2017-04-10 13:23:30 15925 [Note] InnoDB: Using CPU crc32 instructions
Apr 10 13:23:30 server mysqld[15926]: 2017-04-10 13:23:30 15925 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 128.0M
Apr 10 13:23:30 server mysqld[15926]: 2017-04-10 13:23:30 15925 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
Apr 10 13:24:00 server mysql[15820]:    ...fail!
Apr 10 13:24:00 server systemd[1]: mysql.service: Control process exited, code=exited status=1
Apr 10 13:24:00 server systemd[1]: Failed to start LSB: Start and stop the mysql database server daemon.
Apr 10 13:24:00 server systemd[1]: mysql.service: Unit entered failed state.
Apr 10 13:24:00 server systemd[1]: mysql.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
```

what is `Failed to start LSB: Start and stop the mysql database server daemon.`
before installing 5.6 the 5.7 version was working fine but now its like this.

the `/var/log/mysql/errors.log` is empty and these are the `/var/log/syslog` last lines

```
Apr 10 13:23:30 server mysqld: 2017-04-10 13:23:30 15925 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
Apr 10 13:23:30 server mysqld_safe: mysqld from pid file /var/lib/mysql/server.pid ended
Apr 10 13:24:00 server /etc/init.d/mysql[16277]: 0 processes alive and '/usr/bin/mysqladmin --defaults-file=/etc/mysql/debian.cnf ping' resulted in
Apr 10 13:24:00 server /etc/init.d/mysql[16277]: #007/usr/bin/mysqladmin: connect to server at 'localhost' failed
Apr 10 13:24:00 server /etc/init.d/mysql[16277]: error: 'Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)'
Apr 10 13:24:00 server /etc/init.d/mysql[16277]: Check that mysqld is running and that the socket: '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' exists!
Apr 10 13:24:00 server /etc/init.d/mysql[16277]:
Apr 10 13:24:00 server mysql[15820]:    ...fail!
Apr 10 13:24:00 server systemd[1]: mysql.service: Control process exited, code=exited status=1
Apr 10 13:24:00 server systemd[1]: Failed to start LSB: Start and stop the mysql database server daemon.
Apr 10 13:24:00 server systemd[1]: mysql.service: Unit entered failed state.
Apr 10 13:24:00 server systemd[1]: mysql.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
```

output of `mysqld_safe`

```
170410 13:33:28 mysqld_safe Logging to syslog.
170410 13:33:28 mysqld_safe Starting mysqld daemon with databases from /var/lib/mysql
170410 13:33:28 mysqld_safe mysqld from pid file /var/lib/mysql/server.pid ended
```

and this is my `/etc/mysql/my.cnf` and there is no `/etc/my.cnf`

```
#
# The MySQL database server configuration file.
#
# You can copy this to one of:
# - "/etc/mysql/my.cnf" to set global options,
# - "~/.my.cnf" to set user-specific options.
#
# One can use all long options that the program supports.
# Run program with --help to get a list of available options and with
# --print-defaults to see which it would actually understand and use.
#
# For explanations see
# http://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql/en/server-system-variables.html

# This will be passed to all mysql clients
# It has been reported that passwords should be enclosed with ticks/quotes
# escpecially if they contain "#" chars...
# Remember to edit /etc/mysql/debian.cnf when changing the socket location.

# Here is entries for some specific programs
# The following values assume you have at least 32M ram

!includedir /etc/mysql/conf.d/
```

Comment: Can you check the MySQL process server log. Probably in `/var/log/mysql/`

Comment: the `/var/log/mysql/errors`.log is empty. I updated the question please have another look. thanks

Comment: Can you check the output from a manual start of the process? Just run `mysqld_safe`

Comment: the output is: `170410 13:33:28 mysqld_safe Logging to syslog.
170410 13:33:28 mysqld_safe Starting mysqld daemon with databases from /var/lib/mysql
170410 13:33:28 mysqld_safe mysqld from pid file /var/lib/mysql/server.pid ended
`

Comment: It is my assumption that you still have a config file in /etc/my.cnf which has parameters that are specific to 5.7, and now trying to load it into 5.6 causes errors. Try launching using the default config file. Also, it has only been 15 minutes since you asked the question, relax, and wait for a proper answer.

Comment: actually there is no /etc/my.cnf file but i have a /etc/mysql/my.cnf file. is it the same?

Answer (score 2):

This problem arrives when your /etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d/mysqld.cnf file is wrongly set. If you recently made changes to this file please revert to the previous one or copy the default one here

```
    #
# The MySQL database server configuration file.
#
# You can copy this to one of:
# - "/etc/mysql/my.cnf" to set global options,
# - "~/.my.cnf" to set user-specific options.
# 
# One can use all long options that the program supports.
# Run program with --help to get a list of available options and with
# --print-defaults to see which it would actually understand and use.
#
# For explanations see
# http://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql/en/server-system-variables.html

# This will be passed to all mysql clients
# It has been reported that passwords should be enclosed with ticks/quotes
# escpecially if they contain "#" chars...
# Remember to edit /etc/mysql/debian.cnf when changing the socket location.

# Here is entries for some specific programs
# The following values assume you have at least 32M ram

[mysqld_safe]
socket      = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
nice        = 0

[mysqld]
#
# * Basic Settings
#
user        = mysql
pid-file    = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid
socket      = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
port        = 3306
basedir     = /usr
datadir     = /var/lib/mysql
tmpdir      = /tmp
lc-messages-dir = /usr/share/mysql
skip-external-locking
#
# Instead of skip-networking the default is now to listen only on
# localhost which is more compatible and is not less secure.
bind-address        = 0.0.0.0
#
# * Fine Tuning
#
key_buffer_size     = 16M
max_allowed_packet  = 16M
thread_stack        = 192K
thread_cache_size       = 8
# This replaces the startup script and checks MyISAM tables if needed
# the first time they are touched
myisam-recover-options  = BACKUP
#max_connections        = 100
#table_open_cache       = 64
#thread_concurrency     = 10
#
# * Query Cache Configuration
#
query_cache_limit   = 1M
query_cache_size        = 16M
#
# * Logging and Replication
#
# Both location gets rotated by the cronjob.
# Be aware that this log type is a performance killer.
# As of 5.1 you can enable the log at runtime!
#general_log_file        = /var/log/mysql/mysql.log
#general_log             = 1
#
# Error log - should be very few entries.
#
log_error = /var/log/mysql/error.log
#
# Here you can see queries with especially long duration
#slow_query_log     = 1
#slow_query_log_file    = /var/log/mysql/mysql-slow.log
#long_query_time = 2
#log-queries-not-using-indexes
#
# The following can be used as easy to replay backup logs or for replication.
# note: if you are setting up a replication slave, see README.Debian about
#       other settings you may need to change.
#server-id      = 1
#log_bin            = /var/log/mysql/mysql-bin.log
#expire_logs_days   = 10
max_binlog_size   = 100M
#binlog_do_db       = include_database_name
#binlog_ignore_db   = include_database_name
#
# * InnoDB
#
# InnoDB is enabled by default with a 10MB datafile in /var/lib/mysql/.
# Read the manual for more InnoDB related options. There are many!
#
# * Security Features
#
# Read the manual, too, if you want chroot!
# chroot = /var/lib/mysql/
#
# For generating SSL certificates I recommend the OpenSSL GUI "tinyca".
#
# ssl-ca=/etc/mysql/cacert.pem
# ssl-cert=/etc/mysql/server-cert.pem
# ssl-key=/etc/mysql/server-key.pem
```

Answer (score 0):

Stop mysql service:

```
sudo service mysql stop
```

Remove mysql:

```
sudo apt-get remove mysql
sudo apt-get purge mysql
```

Then issue a `whereis mysql` command in terminal and remove all of the locations that command lists using `rm -rf` command. For example `rm -rf /etc/mysql` .

Then reinstall the version of mysql you desire. All should work as expected.

Comment: i did as you said but `apt-get remove mysql` got me error so I used `apt-get remove mysql*` and `sudo apt-get purge mysql*`. and removed the found directories in the commands abov so reinstalled it but its steel the same. no change and not started

Comment: is that your complete `mysql.cnf` file?

Comment: issue this command then try to start mysql `rm -rf /var/run/mysqld/*`

Comment: I did as you said ant again this is happening: `Job for mysql.service failed because the control process exited with error code. See "systemctl status mysql.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
`

Comment: I am starting to think Is it possible to install mysql 5.6 in ubuntu 16.04?

Comment: yes, that should not be an issue, you are just not getting a clean new install because the config from previous install has been left behind. I have faced this issue multiple times and have solved it, each time with a slightly different cause being present.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/141442/discussion-between-coderodour-and-mohammad-fallah-rasoulnejad).

Answer (score 0):

Just check if you db has been given the rights to write the logs give it the logs writing rights and this will get resolved .

Answer (score 0):

1)First remove  already installed mysql-server using--
    sudo apt-get remove --purge mysql-server mysql-client mysql-common

2)Then clean all files
    sudo apt-get autoremove

3)Then install mysql-server --
    sudo apt-get remove -f mysql-server

4)Start mysql server--
    sudo systemctl start mysql

5)Check status of mysql-server--
    systemctl status mysql